# Binary Search returning wrong value

Tags: ruby

I am facing some problems in developing an efficient Binary search algorithm in Ruby with reference to [this site](http://www.cprogramming.com/discussionarticles/sorting_and_searching.html)

**Correct Answer:** Return a value -1432
**Received Answer:** Nil

Code is as follows:

```
def bsearch(a, k)

lower = 0
upper = a.length-1

while a[upper].to_f> k.to_f and a[lower].to_f< k.to_f
    low_diff = k.to_f -a[lower].to_f
    range_diff = a[upper].to_f-a[lower].to_f
    count_diff = upper-lower
    range = ((low_diff/range_diff) * (count_diff))  + lower

    if k.to_f > a[range].to_f
        lower = range+1
    elsif k.to_f <  a[range].to_f
        upper =range-1
    else    
        lower = range
    end 
end
if k =a[lower]
    return lower
else
    return nil
end
end
```

Please help me out with the logic.

Comment: You know [`Array#bsearch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch), don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Like @vacawama says use `==` instead of `=` in last `if` condition:

```
if k == a[lower]
```

And use `&&` instead of `and` in `while` condition:

```
while a[upper].to_f > k.to_f && a[lower].to_f < k.to_f
```

My output on this code:

```
more ./bsearch.rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby
def bsearch(a, k)
    lower = 0
    upper = a.length-1
    while a[upper].to_f > k.to_f && a[lower].to_f < k.to_f
        low_diff = k.to_f - a[lower].to_f
        range_diff = a[upper].to_f - a[lower].to_f
        count_diff = upper-lower
        range = ((low_diff / range_diff) * (count_diff))  + lower
        if k.to_f > a[range].to_f
            lower = range + 1
        elsif k.to_f <  a[range].to_f
            upper = range - 1
        else    
            lower = range
        end 
    end
    if k == a[lower]
        return lower
    else
        return nil
    end
end

puts bsearch([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)
```

Is a:

```
./bsearch.rb
2.0
```